# python decorator and wrapper function debug

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper, python-decorators

I'm studying the decorator and the wrapper by experimenting examples and I found the behavior of decorator that I can't understand.

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function():
        print "wrapper is executed before {}".format(original_function.__name__)
        return original_function() # Try it without ()
    return wrapper_function

@decorator_function 
def display():
    print("display function ran!")
```

when I run above function:

```
In [59]: display()
wrapper is executed before display
display function ran!
```

However, when I move the print function outside of the wrapper, it seems the wrapper doesn't run at all. (Probably it ran but I don't see the evidence.)

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function():
        #print "wrapper is executed before {}".format(original_function.__name__)
        return original_function() # Try it without ()
    print "wrapper is executed before {}".format(original_function.__name__)    
    return wrapper_function

@decorator_function 
def display():
    print("display function ran!")
```

Then I don't see "wrapper is executed before..." anymore. How come?
What am I missing here?

```
In [63]: display()
display function ran!
```

Answer (score 1):

The decorator executes when your code *loads*, while the wrapper executes when your code *runs*.  If I dump your second example into a file `example.py` and run it like this:

```
pythohn -i example.py
```

I see:

```
wrapper is executed before display
>>>
```

That was the decorator running.  Now if I call `display()`, I see the output from that function:

```
>>> display()
display function ran!
>>>
```

I don't see the output from the decorator here because *it already ran*.

Comment: More precisely, "wrapper is executed" is printed at the time `display` is defined (which is when `decorator_function` actually executes).